# How to create a custom action endpoint that corresponds to put and executes a function in the model class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Am using Django Rest Framework: v3.7 and Django v1.11 and Dynamic Rest v1.9.2

I have the following in my MyModel Class:

```
class MyModel():
    # .. fields declared here..

    def change_status(self):
        #... other code not crucial
        allowed = self.status in possible_new_states
        if allowed:
            return self.save()
        return True
```

I have the following ViewSet

```
from dynamic_rest.viewsets import DynamicModelViewSet
# from rest_framework.decorators import action # for DRF 3.8
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route # for DRF 3.7
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyModelViewSet(DynamicModelViewSet):
    """
    VendorQuotations API.
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['put']) # use this for DRF 3.7
    # @action(detail=True, methods=['put']) # use this for DRF 3.8 and above
    def status(self, request, pk=None):
        """Update the status."""
```

And the following Serializer:

```
class VendorQuotationSerializer(DynamicModelSerializer):
```

The [DynamicModelSerializer](https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest/blob/master/dynamic_rest/serializers.py#L781) inherits from `serializers.ModelSerializer` and the [DyanmicModelViewSet](https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest/blob/master/dynamic_rest/viewsets.py#L418) inherits from `viewsets.ModelViewSet`

I wanted to have an endpoint like /my_models/:id/change_status to point at the `status` method in the viewset which in turn somehow execute the `change_status` method at the model level.

I looked at django rest docs and did copy the example for the [change_password](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions) but I am not sure how to connect the dots between the viewset and the model.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ruddra's answer is great but instead of performing a custom lookup, you should use the existing `get_object()` method that already takes care of `404` and checks permissions(very important!)

```
from rest_framework import status

# from rest_framework.decorators import action # for DRF 3.8
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route # for DRF 3.7

@detail_route(methods=['put']) # use this for DRF 3.7
# @action(detail=True, methods=['put']) # use this for DRF 3.8 and above
def status(self, request, pk):
   obj = self.get_object()
   changed_status = obj.change_status()
   return Response({'success':True, "status_changed": changed_status},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Yes you are right, your code does auto check for 404 and permissions. Thank you! I have edited your code to add in the imports and made clear how to use the decorator for 3.7 DRF which I am using and the latest for DRF3.8

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
...

@action(detail=True, methods=['put'], name='Change Status',  url_path='change-status', url_name='change_status')
def status(self, request, pk):
    try:
       obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
       changed_status = obj.change_status()
       return Response({'success':True, "status_changed": changed_status}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExists:
       return Response({'success':False}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I accepted @Ken4scholars answer because his code auto check for 404. Thanks for your response as well :)